# Select first five checkbox in a table using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an html table with 50 rows and each row contains a checkbox. I need to select first five checkbox in the table using jquery by clicking on a button.

```
<table>
  <tr class="asd"><td><input type='checkbox'></td></tr>
  <tr class="asd"><td><input type='checkbox'></td></tr>
  <tr class="asd"><td><input type='checkbox'></td></tr>
  <tr class="asd"><td><input type='checkbox'></td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Please, provide us some code to look. Have you try something so far?

Comment: Please avoid using inline styles... [Why use CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Why_use_CSS)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the first 5 checkboxes using [`:lt()`](http://api.jquery.com/lt-selector)selector as follows:

```js
$("button").click(function () {
    $("table tr :checkbox:lt(5)").prop("checked", true);
})
```

```css
table {
   float: left;
    width:100%;
    text-align: left;
    border: 1px solid #FFB76D;
}
caption span {
    border:1px solid #FFB76D;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    display:block;
    font-size:14px;
    color: #222222;
    background: #FFB76D;
    padding:5px 0px;
}
tr td {
    background-color: #FFF;
    color: #555555;
    height: 40px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #FFB76D;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 0 0 0 10px;"
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" class="content_data sticky-enabled tableheader-processed sticky-table">
    <caption><span>testing</span>

    </caption>
    <thead></thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="odd">
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" value="7491874" class="row_id_checkbox" name="empid" />
            </td>
            <td>7491874</td>
            <td>Amir Moinfar MD</td>
            <td>36</td>
            <td>Thank you</td>
            <td>09/15/2014</td>
            <td>Q</td>
            <td><a href=""><span class="row_goto_btn"></span></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="even">
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" value="7491874" class="row_id_checkbox" name="empid" />
            </td>
            <td>7491874</td>
            <td>asdad</td>
            <td>36</td>
            <td>Thank you</td>
            <td>09/15/2014</td>
            <td>Q</td>
            <td><a href=""><span class="row_goto_btn"></span></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="odd">
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" value="7491874" class="row_id_checkbox" name="empid" />
            </td>
            <td>7491874</td>
            <td>Amir Moinfar MD</td>
            <td>36</td>
            <td>Thank you</td>
            <td>09/15/2014</td>
            <td>Q</td>
            <td><a href=""><span class="row_goto_btn"></span></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="even">
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" value="7491874" class="row_id_checkbox" name="empid" />
            </td>
            <td>7491874</td>
            <td>asdad</td>
            <td>36</td>
            <td>Thank you</td>
            <td>09/15/2014</td>
            <td>Q</td>
            <td><a href=""><span class="row_goto_btn"></span></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="odd">
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" value="7491874" class="row_id_checkbox" name="empid" />
            </td>
            <td>7491874</td>
            <td>Amir Moinfar MD</td>
            <td>36</td>
            <td>Thank you</td>
            <td>09/15/2014</td>
            <td>Q</td>
            <td><a href=""><span class="row_goto_btn"></span></a>

            </td>
        </tr>
         <tr class="even">
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" value="7491874" class="row_id_checkbox" name="empid" />
            </td>
            <td>7491874</td>
            <td>asdad</td>
            <td>36</td>
            <td>Thank you</td>
            <td>09/15/2014</td>
            <td>Q</td>
            <td><a href=""><span class="row_goto_btn"></span></a>

            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<button>select 5</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

A small example how to solve:

```
 var elemens =     $( "table input:checkbox" );

 for(var i = 0 ; i <5; i++){
 //do your logic
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/ucxz20Lh/)

```
$(function() {
    $("table input[type=checkbox]").slice(0,5).prop('checked', true);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use **lt** (less than) modifier.

```
$('#table input[type="checkbox"]:lt(5)').prop('checked', true);
```

Here's JSBin: http://jsbin.com/gacebekuhebu/2/edit

Updated JSBin with the changes that weren't saved for first time. Press "Run with JS" and then press the button.

Comment: @TusharGupta, sorry, somehow JSBin didn't save my latest changes (there was even no button). I've updated bin again: http://jsbin.com/gacebekuhebu/2/edit
You just need to press "Run with JS" and then press a button. It will work.

Comment: @WhiteAngel hi, If you have an improved answer, please edit your answer and update it there rather than in comments, so that the downvotes might be reverted (*downvotes gets locked after 5 minutes and can be reverted only if the post is edited later*)